# Cannot assign "<Customer: Customer object (2)>": "Order.customer" must be a "Product" instance

Tags: python, django

I am building an e-commerce website using django.Whenever i try to fill the checkout form and submit the form it shows me this error: "Cannot assign "<Customer: Customer object (2)>": "Order.customer" must be a "Product" instance."

I am really confuse here I got stuck here

Here is my Views.py for checkout :

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post(self, request):
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        customer = request.session.get('customer')
        products = Product.get_products_id(list(cart.keys()))
        #print(fname, phone, address, products, cart, customer)


        for product in products:
            order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer),product=product,fname=fname, price=product.price,phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))
        
            order.save()
        request.session['cart'] = {}

        return redirect('cart')
```

Here is my Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod   
    def get_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()


class Brand(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_brands():
        return Brand.objects.all()



class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='UNCATEGORIZED')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='NoBrand')
    price = models.FloatField()


    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products():
        return Product.objects.all()


    @staticmethod
    def get_products_by_category(category_id):
        if category_id:
            return Product.objects.filter(category=category_id)
        else:
            return Product.get_all_products()


    @staticmethod
    def get_brands_by_products(brand_id):
        if brand_id:
            return Product.objects.filter(brand=brand_id)
        else:
            return Product.get_all_products()


    @staticmethod
    def get_products_id(ids):
        return Product.objects.filter(id__in=ids)


class Customer(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    email = models.EmailField( default=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,  default=1)




    def register(self):
        self.save()

    def get_customer(phone_number):
        try:
            return Customer.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        except:
            return False

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)


    @staticmethod
    def placeOrder(self):
        return self.save()
```

Here is the Order Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)


    @staticmethod
    def placeOrder(self):
        return self.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your customer field is a ForeignKey to `"Product"` not to the `"Customer"` model.

```
class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Change this field to

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```